# Angular2 : How to display image using Promise?

Tags: image, angular, promise

Following is my component, where I want to display image  using Promise. Following is my code, browser got unresponsive when it run.
Can any one help me to fix this issue.

```
HTML:
<img [src]="getImage()"  />

JS: my.component.ts

// ...

public imageUrl:string;   

constructor() {

   this.imageUrl = "path-to-my-image/image.png";
}

getImage(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        // this.imageUrl  is not static one, it may fetch from the server
      resolve(this.imageUrl);
    });
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use a function call as you are for the value of `src`, Angular's change detection mechanism will call it over and over again. In your case, that will kick off the server calls hundreds or thousands of times.

What you want is something along the lines of:

```
<img [src]="image | async">

ngOnInit() {    
  this.imageUrl = "path-to-my-image/image.png";
  this.image = this.getImageUrl();
}

getImageUrl() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
    // this.imageUrl  is not static one, it may fetch from the server
    resolve(this.imageUrl);
  });
}
```

However, this will work only once. In other words, if you call `getImageUrl` again, nothing will happen. What you probably want is to make the URLs into a stream (observable):

```
<img [src]="image$ | async">

ngOnInit() {    
  this.imageUrl = "path-to-my-image/image.png";
  this.image$ = this.getImageUrl();
}

getImageUrl() {
  return Observable.of(this.imageUrl);
}
```

Comment: Hi, One more doubt. How to solve this issue when list of images? I want to user images in side *ngFor. In this case I can not create numbers of Observable object like 'this.image$', Please help me.

code looks like :

<div class="w3-panel" *ngFor="let item of items;">
  <img  [src]="getImage(image.imageUrl)"/>
</div>

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, consider an observable of arrays of url's. Then you can say `<img *ngFor="let image of images$ | async" [src]="image">`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.